# Произвести фильтрацию

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дали задание,вроде простое,но решить не могу.В общем,есть объект и 
 нужно,чтобы в конце выводились только строки содержащие "link":

```
def traverse_object(obj):
    links = []
    # TODO тут надо реализовать нужный код
    return links


base_object = {
    "dsfwe": {
        "list": ["ewfew", 12],
        "link": "https://ya.ru",
        "object_story_spec": {
            "page_id": "641020669346927",
            "video_data": {
                "video_id": "366854860929577",
                "title": "10 лет решаем задачи родителей",
                "message": " Онлайн-школа «Фоксфорд»: +25 баллов к ЕГЭ, +100 к спокойствию родителей!\n⠀\n 10 лет решаем любые образовательные задачи: сдать ОГЭ и ЕГЭ, победить в олимпиаде, поступить в классный вуз, решить любую контрольную и исправить любую оценку!",
                "link_description": "Поможем достичь любой учебной цели!",
                "call_to_action": {
                    "type": "LEARN_MORE",
                    "value": {
                        "link_caption": "foxford.ru",
                        "link": "http://10.foxford.ru/students?utm_source = facebook & utm_medium = cpm & utm_campaign = fox10_reach_feed_parents & utm_content = sochi",
                        "link_format": "VIDEO_LPP"
                    }
                },
                "image_hash": "14e9e5cefa89889bf3443891aee85a12"
            },
            "link": ["https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/", 3]
        },
        "id": "6126978628477"
    }

}

extra_data = [
    "123",
    123,
    {
        "some_obj": base_object
    },
    {
        12: {
            "link": "http://netology.fx.ru",
            12: {
                "ob": {
                    "link": "http://n-group.ru"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]

print(traverse_object(extra_data))
```

Comment: С чем возникла проблема?

Comment: Что значит _'только строки содержащие "link"'_? Вам нужно вернуть список значений из словаря произвольной вложенности, которые получены по ключам, в названии которых есть строка "link"? Я правильно интерпретировал задачу?

Comment: С тем,что просто не могу понять:как именно нужно провести фильтрацию.Смотрю- у меня тут и словарь и список.Короче - полностью переклинило.Вот и хотел спросить,что мне надо сделать?Что необходимо написать в самом коде(вероятно его придется исправить)?

Comment: nomnoms12,да.Совершенно верно

Comment: @ДаниилПопов Я попробовал решить задачу, но проблема возникла со ссылкой, которая находится в списке, который в свою очередь является значением ключа `link`. Вот мои наработки, возможно, они помогут Вам: https://pastebin.com/2A7srkhL.